# jQuery callback event

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I'm developing a simple captcha system that uses jquery to refresh the image if not readable.

```
$('a#reload').click(function(){

    $(this).removeClass('reload').addClass('reloading');

    var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

    $('div#captcha-image img').attr('src', 'captcha/captcha.php?t=' + ts);

    $('input#captcha').focus();

});
```

This code does everything except resetting the reload button to its initial state.

I want to make this function after all the above, like a callback function in ajax.

```
$(this).removeClass('reloading').addClass('reload');
```

This function resets the reload button to its initial normal state, so how to call it after everything passes.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to trigger the addition of the "reload" class only after the new captcha image has loaded completely?

Comment: and I put a sleep(1) in the captcha.php to take some time to process so the changed state of the button can be noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add:

```
 $('div#captcha-image img').load(function(){
     $(a#reload).removeClass('reloading').addClass('reload');
 });
```

So if your image is a valid image and is loaded then .load() will wait until it's done to call the callback and change the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#reload').click(function(){

    $(this).removeClass('reload');

    var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

    $('div#captcha-image img').attr('src', 'captcha/captcha.php?t=' + ts);

    $('input#captcha').focus();

    $(this).removeClass('reloading').addClass('reload');
});
```

This seems trivial, so I'm not sure I understand the question completely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work as that function will be called immediately so that the button goes back to its normal state before the image captcha is processed in the server and returned in the browser, and you will not notice any change in the button state as it is immediately changed back.